# XML pretty-printer with fixed line-width output

Tags: xml, command-line, pretty-print

I need a command-line XML pretty-printer tool that will not overflow given output line width.

All tools I've tried (xmlstarlet, xmllint, xmlindent) overflow line width when printing tags with many attributes. I'll settle if each attribute will be printed at a separate line (while keeping indentation of course).

Tool must be free, runnable on Linux and, preferably, have an Ubuntu package. However, I'll settle for a downloadable library.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Tidy with `-xml` will reformat XML.

Comment: Thanks, it almost works. However I see gives incorrect indentation for the tag right after CDATA. Is it a known issue?